# Steps to enable metrics server on Windows node for Kubernetes HPA

Tags: windows, kubernetes, hpa, metrics-server

Can someone tell me the steps to configure metrics server for windows node in kubernetes. I wanted to incorporate HPA for my windows node deployment.

I was looking for various alternatives and got to know that metrics server has windows support for k8s version v1.15 and later but I can't find the steps to do the same.